# Read Image in grails coming from ipad

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I am all new to this kind of thing. Reading images sent by a client is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
That is an image I receive from that client which is an ipad application. It attaches image to http body and sends it to server with other parameters using ?id=10 etc .
Question is .... How to get that image from its body and write to file system ?

For now I have written a separate servlet to read this image(using request.getInputStream()) and read its bytes then write to file system, which is not good(context gets different).

What to do in grails controller so that it can easily read image. Please help me out. For me it is on high priority. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Grails has file upload support. Let's give an example to simplify things.

In your view you will have a form something like this:

```
<g:form action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myFile" />
</g:form>
```

In your controller you can have something like:

```
class FileController {
    def save = {
        def f = request.getFile('myFile')
        if(!f.empty) {
            def fileName = 'file_xyz'
            f.transferTo( new File('imgs/' + fileName) )
        }
        redirect(action:show)
    }
}
```

If you need to manipulate de image (scale it, crop it....), I suggest ImgScalr. See here: 
http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/